# insert into select using different column in duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

```
INSERT INTO options (owner, name, value, modified)
SELECT owner, name, value, modified, @draft:=draft FROM
(
    ...
) `options`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES(value), modified=@draft
```

Above will error with column count doesn't match row count.

Is there a way I can SELECT a column into @draft without it being included as part of the inserts values but so it's usable in the DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html):

> In the values part of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you can refer to columns in other tables, as long as you do not use `GROUP BY` in the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) part. One side effect is that you must qualify nonunique column names in the values part.

Therefore, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO options (owner, name, value, modified)
  SELECT owner, name, value, modified FROM ( ... ) options2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES(value), modified=options2.draft
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b47c/1).